# Marginal function $\phi(u)=\int_0^\infty f(u^2+r^2)dr$ in $C^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to prove that if $f\colon[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is continuous and $\int_0^\infty f(r^2)dr$ converges, then the function $\phi\colon\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$\phi(u)=\int_0^\infty f(u^2+r^2)dr$$ is in $C^{\frac{1}{2}}$. I am not sure of the best method to use to show that a function is in a fractional continuity space. Do I argue directly or use a Sobolev embedding argument?